# Dockerfile to serve CSS and JS file

Tags: css, docker, dockerfile

I am working on a Dockerfile to serve my index.html, style.css and app.js, but it only serves index.html, I am not sur why, here's my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Nginx runtime as a parent image
FROM nginx:stable

# Copy the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files into the container
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY js/app.js /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY css/style.css /usr/share/nginx/html/


# Expose port 80 for the Nginx server
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx when the container starts
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here's my file structure:

```
AZDO/
├─ css/
│  ├─ style.css
├─ js/
│  ├─ app.js
│  ├─ jquery.min.js
Dockerfile
index.html
```

Not sure where I am going wrong I think it is the COPY statements ?

Comment: How are you verifying the problem? Are you trying to open the files directly, eg `http://localhost:<port>/app.js`? Does that not work?

Comment: I note that you're putting all the files in the same `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory without their associated sub-directories `js/` and `css/`. Is that what the problem is? If so, you just need `COPY js/app.js /usr/share/nginx/html/js/`, etc

Comment: I think the problem you are having is the destination of your css file is ending up in html folder - not css folder. Maybe try this or copy a whole folder: COPY css/style.css /usr/share/nginx/html/css. OR better COPY css /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: You are right @phil, it had to be a different subdirectory, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that you're looking at the wrong path.

The `COPY` command inserts  only the file/folder you specify directly. Not the full path.
So your CSS file for example should be here: `/usr/share/nginx/html/style.css`. Note the missing folder `./css/`.

Either you have to do something like this:

```
COPY css/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY js/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Or wrap the entire project in a sub-folder and copy it all at once:

```
ZDO/
├─ src/
│  ├─ css/
│  │ ├─ style.css
│  ├─ js/
│  │  ├─ app.js
│  │  ├─ jquery.min.js
│  index.html
Dockerfile
```

```
COPY src/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This has the added benefit of reducing the layers of your docker image.